# Rails 4 has_many :through NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is probably a simple solution but I am stumped.

I want to display a table with:
Event Name | EventAthlete Result | EventAthlete Score

If I check the data in the pry console, everything is linked properly.
eg. `@athlete.event_athletes.first.event.name`
This returns the correct name of the event.

However, when I try to display the data in the browser (i.e. `ea.event.name`), I receive the error:

"NoMethodError at /athletes/1
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

I suspect this may be an issue with strong parameters.

https://github.com/thaczuk/scoring/tree/eventScoring
Please advise.

**Models**

```
class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :competition
  belongs_to  :competition_category
  has_many    :event_athletes
  has_many    :events, through: :event_athletes
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :competition
  has_many    :event_athletes
  has_many    :athletes, through: :event_athletes
end

class EventAthlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :athlete
  belongs_to  :event
end
```

**Controller**

```
class AthletesController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def show
    @athlete = Athlete.find(params[:id])
    binding.pry
  end

  ...

private
    def athlete_params
      params.require(:athlete).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :gender, :competition_id, :competition_category_id)
    end
end
```

**View**

```
%div
  %table.table
    %thead
      %tr
        %th(width="30%") Event
        %th Result
        %th Score

    %tbody
      -@athlete.event_athletes.each do |ea|
        %tr
          %td= ea.event.name
          %td= ea.result
          %td= ea.score
```

Comment: Can you give some background information about what it is you're exactly doing? I.e. where does the posted code fit into the general framework of yours>

Comment: The full code is available here: https://github.com/thaczuk/scoring/tree/eventScoring

Answer (score 0):

You have one athlete and one event for each of the records here `@athlete.event_athletes.each`

Yout just want to loop all the events for the althete instead of looping all event-atheletes.

What you want to do is:

```
@athelete.events.each do |event|
     %td= event.name
     % ea = EventAthlete.where(athlete_id: @athelte.id, event_id: event.id)
     %td= ea.score
     %td= ea.result
```

Comment: This gives a NoMethodError on ea.score and ea.result

Comment: That means there is no athelete-event combination. The athelete is associated with event(s), but there is no EventAthelete record for them. How are you saving the scores & creating the athelete-event reference?

Comment: The association is there with @athlete.event_athletes but not with ea: [link]https://gist.github.com/thaczuk/7419846